# How do you reply to a RabbitMQ RPC client with multiple messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ in an RPC environment where each remote call will take a significant amount of time, producing results continually.  I want the results to be delivered to the client as they are generated.

I started with the standard tutorial RPC example, then modified it to use "Direct Reply-to". I publish all the intermediate results back to an "anonymous exclusive callback queue", with out acknowledging the original request.  When processing is complete, I send a final message back to the client and then acknowledge the original request.  But the client is only seeing the first intermediate message.  My client happens to be in PHP and my server is in Python, but I suspect that is not relevant. Does anyone have the magic to make this work?  I can post code, but is pretty basic stuff by the cookbook.

Comment: Wellllll, never mind.  Once I cleaned up code for posting an example, I got it to work, by just correctly implementing what I said in the original question

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.  The following worked:

php client:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class RpcClient {
    private $connection;
    private $channel;
    private $callback_queue;
    private $response;
    private $corr_id;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
            'localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest'
        );
        $this->channel = $this->connection->channel();

        list($this->callback_queue, ,) = $this->channel->queue_declare(
            "", false, false, true, false
        );


        # For direct reply-to, need to consume amq.rabbitmq.repy-to, a special queue name
        # Unclear what happens to the declare above
        $this->channel->basic_consume(
                $this->callback_queue, '', false, true,
                false, false, array($this, 'onResponse')
        );
    }

    # This is going to be called once for each message coming back
    public function onResponse($rep) {
        if ($rep->get('correlation_id') == $this->corr_id) {
                $response = json_decode($rep->body, true);
                echo print_r($response['line'], true);
                if ($response['type'] == 'final') {
                        $this->response = $rep->body;
                }
        }
    }

    public function call($message_array) {
        $this->response = null;
        $this->corr_id = uniqid();

        $jsonm = json_encode($message_array);
        $msg = new AMQPMessage(
            $jsonm,
            array(
                'correlation_id' => $this->corr_id,
                ### Not sure which of the next two lines is the correct one... if either....
                ##'reply_to' => 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to' # This is when using direct reply-to
                'reply_to' => $this->callback_queue
            )
        );
        $this->channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'ansiblePB_rpc_queue');
        while (!$this->response) {
            $this->channel->wait();
        }
        return intval($this->response);
    }
}

$ansiblepb_rpc = new RpcClient();
$response = $ansiblepb_rpc->call(array('userID' => 'jb1234', 
                                       'user_display_name' => 'Joe Bloe',
                                       'limit' => '24000'));
echo ' [.] Got ', $response, "\n";
?>
```

Python server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" 1 """
import glob
import json
import platform
import os
import re
import shutil
import subprocess
import time
import yaml

import pika

class RMQmultireply(object):
    """ Generic class to support ansible_playbook on a Rabbit MQ RPC queue"""
    def __init__(self, channel, method, props):
        #""" Constructor.... duh """
        self.channel = channel
        self.method = method
        self.props = props

    def run(self, userID, username, limit):
        """ Run the main guts of the service """

        cmd = ['/home/dhutchin/devel/rmq/multilineoutput']

        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
            intermediate_json_result = json.dumps({'type': 'intermediate', 'line': line})

            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                       routing_key=self.props.reply_to,
                                       properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                           correlation_id=self.props.correlation_id),
                                       body=str(intermediate_json_result))
            #self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=self.method.delivery_tag)

        proc.wait()
        return proc.returncode


def on_request(channel, method, props, jsonstring):
    """ Request has just come in to run ansible_playbook """


    playbook = RMQmultireply(channel, method, props)

    # fork and exec a playbook
    #  Recieve each line of output and send them as received back
    #  to the requestor.
    #  .run does not return until playbook exits.
    # Use "Direct Reply-to" mechanism to return multiple messages to
    # our client.
    request = yaml.load(jsonstring)  # Yes, yaml works better than JSON
    returncode = playbook.run(request['userID'], request['user_display_name'], request['limit'])

    final_json_result = json.dumps({'type': "final", 'line': '', 'rc': returncode})

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                          routing_key=props.reply_to,
                          properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=
                                                          props.correlation_id),
                          body=str(final_json_result))

    # Acknowlege the original message so that RabbitMQ can remove it
    # from the ansiblePB_rpc_queue queue
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


def main():
    """ Its kinda obvious what this does """

    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    except Exception:
        print "pika.BlockingConnection.... failed... maybe RabbitMQ is not running"
        quit()

    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='ansiblePB_rpc_queue')

    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    # auto_ack is turned off by default, so we don't need to specify auto_ack=False
    channel.basic_consume(queue='ansiblePB_rpc_queue', on_message_callback=on_request)

    print " [x] Awaiting RPC requests"
    channel.start_consuming()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```